# How do i verify my Australia visit visa either valid or not without reference number

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, australia, eta

I applied my visit visa through an agency but what i got is 
[image]

i got no reference number.So, how do I know that my visa is valid or not?
The agency said the information given was direct respond from Australia Immigration.

Comment: This clearly says "approved", so what is your actual concern? Do you perhaps not trust your travel agency and you would like to independently verify your ETA status with the Australian authorities?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see that screenshot because it is rather small, but clearly your visa was approved. You can tell this because it says "ETA APPROVAL" at the top, "ETA APPROVED" at the bottom, and it lists a validity date, the period you're authorized to stay, and other conditions. It would not say any of these things if it was not approved.